# Was the Wood in Tales of Goldstone Wood inspired by the Chronicles of Narnia?

Tags: inspiration, the-chronicles-of-narnia, anne-elisabeth-stengl, tales-of-goldstone-wood

*Golden Daughter* describes the Wood as follows:

> The Wood is bigger by far than any mortal mind can comprehend. It is not a world in itself but rather the seat of worlds, containing with its vastness doorways into every realm...

This sounds at least superficially like the Wood between the worlds in *The Magician's Nephew*. With that said, there are some significant differences (such as the fact that you don't enter world through visible pools of water, the fact that it doesn't instantly make you "sleepy" and forget what you were doing, and the absence of Rings or other similar devices).

Was this an intentional parallel (the differences notwithstanding)?

Comment: Short of authorial confirmation, it might be hard to pin down a connection here. Series like Narnia and LotR are such 'classic' fantasy that a lot of authors have probably been inspired by them without even realising it.

Comment: To be fair, this convention is also used in The Nightmare Before Christmas.